# printing dates in a log file

Tags: python, regex

I have a log file with a consistent date in my log file.

ex:

```
date1

date2

...
```

The date means the number of logs in my log file. I was wondering how can print the dates from the log file using Regular expressions

what I have tried:

```
import re

dateRegex = re.compile('^\w{3}\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d')

f = open("logfile.log","r")

for line in f.readlines():
    matches = re.findall(dateRegex,line)
    print matches
```

The output I am getting is (many `[]`):

```
[]
[]
[]
...
...
```

Comment: Put an `if` somewhere to avoid printing when you have no matches. You might also want to print the element of the result list, as opposed to the list itself.

Comment: @nhahtdh sample datetime `Apr 20 07:04:53`

Comment: You forgot to match the date. Try `r'^\w{3}\s\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d'`

Comment: @Jerry no matches still =/ I was wondering is the r is needed when using re.compile? i tested it without the `r` for another case and it worked without it

Comment: @Jerry sorry i didnt see a typo I made

Comment: Yes, you'd be safer with the `r`. It's working right now because `\d` and `\s` don't have special meanings afaik. If you try to work with `\b`, you'll start getting anomalies without `r` :)

Comment: @Jerry if you could write this as the answer I would gladly accept it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten the date:

```
import re

dateRegex = re.compile(r'^\w{3}\s\d\d?\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d')
                             # ^^^^^^^ I added ? to cater for dates between 1 & 9

f = open("logfile.log","r")

for line in f.readlines():
    matches = re.findall(dateRegex,line)
    if matches:                # Check if there are matches
        print matches[0]       # Print first element of list returned by findall
```

I think that you can use `re.match` instead, since you're testing line by line and using the beginning of line anchor:

```
import re

dateRegex = re.compile(r'\w{3}\s\d\d?\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d')

f = open("logfile.log","r")

for line in f.readlines():
    matches = re.match(dateRegex,line)
    if matches:
        print matches.group()
```